# TFS in VS 2012 Team Explorer only shows one projecct

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using TFS for the first time.  I open Visual studio 2012 and click 'connect to team foundation server.  This brings up the Source Control Explorer.  After connecting to the service, the folder list on the left is full with all items on the server, but the Team Exploerer - Connect field shows the server drop down, but only one team project under the collection.  How do I get all team projects to list in the Team Explorer window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot list all team projects in the Team Explorer window (like in TFS2010). 
You can only change the active team project.

Comment: ok thanks.  i noticed if I click connect, the pop up window appears with the correct server and team collection, but only the one project is listed.  How do I get all the projects listed in the pop up?

Comment: If in the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" window you don't see all team projects from the team collection then it means that you don't have the permissions to access those team projects.